# AWS IOT partition design

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis

Problem : There 1 million temperature monitoring IOT devices sending temperature data every minute.

We need to query this data to get minimum, maximum, average temperate for a given HH:MM, either filtering specific devices, or ALL devices.

If any of you have implemented IOT analytics, what would a high level architecture look like ? This is what I have in mind :

IOT -> Kinesis -> S3 -> ATHENA / REDSHIFT
[image]

Each device could send simple json data:
{"device_id": "101", "temperature" : "65.4"}

Question :

1. Should I use columnar data format like Parquet since we're doing aggregate queries? But will it work for fast data ingestion ? and will it work fast for queries that filter by specific device?
2. Which column should the partition key be ? My guess is timestamp since the WHERE clause is on YY:DD:HH:MM? Should the json include the timestamp as a column ?
3. If so, how does GLUE schema's timestamp partition tie in with S3 which is already partitioned by YYYY-MM-DD-HH ?

Comment: Did you end up using this architecture? How did it go? How good/bad is Athena's performance?

Answer (score 3):

There's one important parameter you don't specify: how long after a data point has been collected do you need to be able to query it? In other words, if you do statistics for a particular minute like you describe, how quickly do you expect to be able to run that query? If it's within a minute, five minutes, 30 minutes, or hours makes a huge difference in how to architect the solution.

Kinesis Firehose has a buffer with which you can tune the size of the files delivered to S3. You can set targets for file size and time, so that the buffer is written once it reaches a certain size or once the oldest data point in it is a certain age. Bigger file sizes are better for analytics, but the trade off is of course that it introduces a delay in the stream of data.

Kinesis Data Firehose has a [Record Format Conversion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/record-format-conversion.html) feature that can transform incoming JSON data to Parquet or ORC on the fly. In general columnar formats are better for analytics, as they allow columns to be skipped while reading, they do compression, and allow for skipping of blocks in some situations. For your use case it would probably result in smaller files than JSON, and since the data is roughly ordered by time there would be opportunity for Athena to skip big chunks of the files when you look for a specific minute, or for a specific device. For queries that don't look at the device that column wouldn't have to be read either. (Note here that in theory this is true for both Parquet and ORC, but I haven't had much luck with ORC and Athena in practice, if you try please report back to me, but if you don't have the time go with Parquet, because in Athena it has in my experience lived up to these promises much better).

The downside of using Record Format Conversion is that you will have to buffer for longer, the target file size is much larger than for regular deliveries. This makes sense as you don't want to have a lot of small Parquet files, it will gain you nothing.

Kinesis Data Firehose delivers files partitioned by hour, which means you can create Athena tables with a partition key that covers either just the date or include the hour by adding partitions either for each `…/YYYY/MM/DD/` prefix, or each `…/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/` prefix (partition keys of tables don't have to match the "directories" of S3 prefixes, you don't need to have three or four partition keys, you only need one and it either covers just the date or the date and hour). I would use [Partition Projection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html) to avoid having to add partitions manually (here's [an example on how to configure it for Kinesis Data Firehose data sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-kinesis-firehose-example.html) which uses a partition key covering the hour).

Whether to choose a partition key that covers the date or the date and hour depends on your most common queries. If almost all queries are the one you mention that looks at a particular minute then having partitions for each hour prefix makes the most sense. With that setup Athena will be able to skip all partitions but the one the minute belongs to, and then it will be able to skip reading a lot of the data inside that partition because it will be sorted roughly on time and Parquet keeps enough metadata to know say which blocks contain which ranges for each column.

I'm not sure what you mean by your last question about Glue. Hopefully you should be able to avoid using Glue altogether for this architecture (if we don't count the Glue Data Catalog).

Whether or not to go with Record Format Conversion depends on how much data we're talking about and how quickly you need to be able to query it. If you need to be able to query it almost immediately you can't buffer for very long, and you can almost definitely not use Record Format Conversion unless the amount of data is huge (one million data points with two numbers, say 16 bytes, will take a couple of minutes to fill the minimum file size, and with compression even longer).

If you don't go for Record Format Conversion each query will be more expensive, but you will be able to run the query quicker – which might be worth it.

Comment: This is a great comment and reading about partition projection got me excited. Let's say I didn't want to wait for a minute before a measurement can be queried, what's my best alternative?